# Emacs navigating location history

Tags: emacs, navigation, location, history, buffer

In Emacs I can edit something at location 'b' and do C-u C-Space to back to the last place I was, location 'a', in the buffer. But how do I get back to 'b'? In short instead of popping the mark ring stack, I want its history preserved.

I have read the documentation on using bookmarks, registers and tags but I have to manually set those. As in the case of returning from a single detour using C-u C-Space I don't want to have to remember to set anything.

I have many use-cases for this, but one that comes up most often is going back and forth between the "import ..." section which is usually at the top of my program and my current edit location.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to move forward and backward in Emacs' mark ring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393834/how-to-move-forward-and-backward-in-emacs-mark-ring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is indeed a duplicate of "How to move forward and backward in Emacs' mark ring". Thanks Sean!

Answer (score 1):

C-x C-x swaps the position of the point (i.e. the cursor) and the mark. You can use this to go back and forth between two positions.