# Highlight mark-ring locations in Emacs

Tags: emacs, highlight

Would anyone know how to get the past locations of the `mark-ring` to highlight when pressing <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>C-Space</kbd>, and to remove whenever something other than  <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>C-Space</kbd> is pressed?

Maybe with only a history of let's say 5 not to have a full screen of highlights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've started writing a minor mode to do that. You can get it at GitHub:

https://github.com/kleiba/visual-mark-ring-mode

However, please be advised that this is a very preliminary 0.1 version - it might not work at all for you.

(P.S.: If anyone is willing to help me out in improving this minor-mode, I'd be grateful for any contribution.)

Comment: The old M-x butterfly strikes again. :)

Comment: Well done! It does exactly what I want. Bonus points: do you know of a way to move through the ring the other way?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393834/how-to-move-forward-and-backward-in-emacs-mark-ring) - however, the current version of the above minor-mode supports only `C-u C-SPC`, one of the many weaknesses.

Comment: For me that's a strength: The only moment I'd use it is with that key combination! (Now im curious...when to use it otherwise?)

Comment: Well, for one, you might have bound `set-mark-command` to a different key than `C-SPC`. For instance, by default it's also set to `C-@` which my mode does not handle. In addition, there might be other commands that should keep the markers visible, such as, e.g. `recenter-top-bottom` (`C-l`).

Comment: I question the usefulness of this.  The point of saving to the mark-ring is to get back after you've travelled a long distance.  But by that time, the mark would be off the screen most of the time.  Maybe there is some way to make this generally useful.  Sublime Text's minimap view would be helpful for this.

Comment: @event_jr To be honest, I've had similar concerns. But I'm very open to changing the way this little mode works right now to make it more generally useful.

Answer (score 2):

To highlight the locations in the mark ring:

```
(defun highlight-ring-marks ()
  (let ((markstr (char-to-string 8595)))
    (put-text-property 0 1 'face '((:background "yellow") (:foreground "black"))
                       markstr)
    (mapc (lambda (m)
            (let ((ovl (make-overlay m m)))
              (overlay-put ovl 'after-string markstr)
              (overlay-put ovl 'mark-ring-pointer t)))
          mark-ring)))
```

To dehighlight them:

```
(defun dehighlight-ring-marks ()
  (mapc (lambda (ovl)
          (and (overlay-get ovl 'mark-ring-pointer)
               (delete-overlay ovl)))
        (overlays-in (point-min) (point-max))))
```

With those in place, all that remains is to connect the highlight code to `C-u C-SPC` and add the dehighlight code to `pre-command-hook`, so that the indicators are removed when the user presses a key:

```
(require 'cl)   ; for lexical-let

(defun set-mark-and-highlight (pos)
  (interactive "P")
  (set-mark-command pos)
  (when pos
    (highlight-ring-marks))
  ;; call dehighlight-ring-marks, but only once
  (lexical-let (hookfn)
    (setq hookfn (lambda ()
                   (dehighlight-ring-marks)
                   (remove-hook 'pre-command-hook hookfn)))
    (add-hook 'pre-command-hook hookfn)))
```

Finally, bind the new command to <kbd>C-SPC</kbd>:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-SPC") 'set-mark-and-highlight)
```

Comment: It is almost perfect, though I am the one to blame for not being specific enough. It would be nice instead of those arrow signs to have numbers written in them so you know how many places you have to go back. Could you add it?

Comment: It's easy to change the mark string to whatever you like, just move its creation into the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Some elisp to do what you asked
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VisibleMark

Also google shows someone added to that code on their own site
http://retroj.net/visible-mark
I am currently trying that out to highlight the last 3 marks.
Added visible-mark.el to my load path. Added this to my init file

```
(require 'visible-mark)
(defface visible-mark-face1
  '((((type tty) (class mono))
     (:inverse-video t))
    (t (:background "gold4"))) "")
(defface visible-mark-face2
  '((((type tty) (class mono)))
    (t (:background "DarkOrange4"))) "")
(defface visible-mark-face3
  '((((type tty) (class mono)))
    (t (:background "red4"))) "")
(setq visible-mark-faces (quote (visible-mark-face1 visible-mark-face2 visible-mark-face3)))

; highlight the last 3 marks
(setq visible-mark-max 3)
; globally activate visible-mark-mode
(global-visible-mark-mode)
```